# How to load Image asynchronously in WP7?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7

I am binding imagesource from server. While binding the image in not shown unless it is completely loaded. what i want is a technique (codes will be more preferable) to show "loading.." in the image unless image is loaded. 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [Jeff Wilcox SmoothImage](https://github.com/jeffwilcox/thejeffwilcox/blob/master/src/Shared/Images/SmoothImage.cs) to show one default image that you already on your app, and then set the "alternate" image that after loading it will show with a smooth animation!

Comment: can you provide an example..@pedro lamas

Comment: Don't have one at hand (using phone right now), but believe me it's not that hard to use it! :)

Comment: am sorry but i couldnot get any idea for using SmoothImage so can you provide me some example with code if possible.

Comment: hey guys i am still waiting for the answer. Is anybody out there to help me out...